# maximum and minimum distributions

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that X is uniformly distributed on the interval [0,10] and suppose that Y=2X. Note that X is uniformly distributed on the interval of [0,20]

Find the probability that min(X,20-Y)>7

**What I know / tried**

I know that the minimum function is given by the following equation;

$f_v(x)=nf_X(x)(1-F_X(x))^{n-1}$

so n = 2

If X and Y were iid R.V. then I could plug either in for $f_X(x)$ but when I put in a solution using one or the other here I get answers that are way, way off. How do I use this formula with two dependent distributions?

Comment: We want  $20-Y\gt 7$.  So we want $20-2X\gt 7$, so we want $X\lt 6.5$.  We also want $X\gt 7$. Kind of hard to reconcile!

Comment: why 20-Y > 7? Why not X>7 from the get go? I'm sorry, the book doesn't explain this concept well.

Comment: I dealt with the condition $20-Y\gt 7$ first. Could have done it in the opposite order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want  $20-Y\gt 7$.  So we want $20-2X\gt 7$, so we want $X\lt 6.5$.

We also want $X\gt 7$.

The two conditions are incompatible.